# Html canvas not rendered when attached then drawn then detached using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, html5-canvas

I am using kendo-ui drawing api to get the screenshot of a section of the webpage. The api returns an image as data uri that use then to generate an image node.

```
data = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0...."
var imageNode = document.createElement("img");
imageNode.src = data;
```

Then i create a new canvas and append it to the body element, i draw the image above on it and in the end i detach it from the body using jQuery

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.id = "some_random_id";
canvas.width = 1650;
canvas.height = 720;

$("body").append($(canvas));

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(imageNode, 0, 0);

$(canvas).detach();

// in the end i return this canvas in the callback so that any module that requested it can append it wherever and use it
callback(canvas);
```

The problem is that the image is only rendered on the canvas sometimes, not always. It used to work before only couple of days i got this issue.

I tried in chrome debugger only to find that when i put a break point on the line where i detach the image and pause it in debugger

```
$(canvas).detach();
```

and then resume the debugger it seems to work always
but without debugger it only works randomly.

I thought it might be a timing issue so i tried to do a timeout after detaching the canvas and then do the callback for example

```
   $(canvas).detach();
     setTimeout(function () {
        callback(canvas);
     }, 200);
```

but it still renders randomly not everytime

Comment: I've tried creating a fiddle but you haven't provided enough code to construct one with. My first guess is that you should check to make sure the image is loaded before trying to append. This is easily accomplished on an image object with the .onload method

Comment: Wow!! that was right on target @zfrisch. I moved all my code to imageNode.onload method and it works like a charm. I am a beginner on stack overflow I dont know how i can upvote your comment. Thanks a ton!!